# Setting PHP Global Variables from Command Line pre-execution?

Tags: java, php, apache, global-variables, cgi

I'm in the process of making a custom webserver in Java, and right now I'm getting PHP to work. The problem I'm having, is that while I can throw the PHP file in command line and get a parsed result, and that's all fine and dandy, how do I start throwing in things like GET/POST/SERVER variables? Streams from the connection? I want to make all PHP scripts compatible, but online I have found very little documentation on how to accomplish this.

Comment: You could use environment variables and use [`$_ENV`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php).

Comment: @AlexisKing You gave me an idea, could I prepend me setting all of these variables in some <?php $_GET['blah'] = 'sdfsdf'; ?> fashion? Or is this nonstandard/invalid for some reason?